# Does MarkLogic support shared-disk failover using AWS Elastic File System?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

While the documentation is rather clear and specific on what is supported (not AWS Elastic File System), as well as the pros/cons of shared disk failover, I figure it's worth at least asking if anyone has tried to use AWS Elastic File System in a shared disk failover configuration or if that's a supported option for shared disk failover.

Information about AWS EFS: https://aws.amazon.com/efs/

MarkLogic Documentation that indicates it's not supported: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/failover#id_88928

Any thoughts and insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs list what is explicitly "Supported".  Those are the configurations tested and known to work well.  For any specifics on what that means wrt to support service I suggest asking your account rep.

As for 'tried EFS' - I have personally tried it and know of a few others who have for a very quick 'will it crash test'. I looked at the specs and in my opinion EFS seems like a possible viable option. It has characteristics very close to NFS.
Performance is likely to vary dramatically depending on many factors.  An interesting statement from AWS is that performance *increases* with the used filesystem size.  But unlike EBS you don't pre-allocate.  So I don't know how the performance would be as your database grew from small to large(er).

It will be interesting to see how well it works in real world use cases. There are subtleties in shared network file systems that may not surface without exhausting testing, if then.  If EFS is the only redundancy for HA and DA that puts it at a risk multiplier -- not well tested times a single point of possible failure.